# SQL Server 2005 login password change variance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, passwords

We have a SQL Server 2005 database running on a Windows Server 2003 machine.  This database is now required to enforce password change variance for its logins, i.e. new passwords should differ from old ones by at least n characters.  The logins use SQL Server Authentication.  We have Enforce Password Policy checked for these logins, but the Windows password complexity policy doesn't inlcude the required variance rule.

Is there a way to implement this rule with a trigger or some other mechanism within SQL Server?  We'd rather not resort to something exotic, like trying to decompile and edit passfilt.dll.

Let me know if I've left out any useful information, and thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get to the clear text password, so you can't validate the diff...

Comment: Depends on how the password change is handled.  You could do it through a web form and capture the user input, then apply it to the master db.  Passwords are hashed for a reason, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Levenshtein distance:

```
CREATE FUNCTION edit_distance_within(@s nvarchar(4000), @t nvarchar(4000), @d int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sl int, @tl int, @i int, @j int, @sc nchar, @c int, @c1 int,
    @cv0 nvarchar(4000), @cv1 nvarchar(4000), @cmin int
  SELECT @sl = LEN(@s), @tl = LEN(@t), @cv1 = '', @j = 1, @i = 1, @c = 0
  WHILE @j <= @tl
    SELECT @cv1 = @cv1 + NCHAR(@j), @j = @j + 1
  WHILE @i <= @sl
  BEGIN
    SELECT @sc = SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1), @c1 = @i, @c = @i, @cv0 = '', @j = 1, @cmin = 4000
    WHILE @j <= @tl
    BEGIN
      SET @c = @c + 1
      SET @c1 = @c1 - CASE WHEN @sc = SUBSTRING(@t, @j, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      IF @c > @c1 SET @c = @c1
      SET @c1 = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@cv1, @j, 1)) + 1
      IF @c > @c1 SET @c = @c1
      IF @c < @cmin SET @cmin = @c
      SELECT @cv0 = @cv0 + NCHAR(@c), @j = @j + 1
    END
    IF @cmin > @d BREAK
    SELECT @cv1 = @cv0, @i = @i + 1
  END
  RETURN CASE WHEN @cmin >= @d AND @c >= @d THEN @c ELSE -1 END
  END
```

Create this function, then call the distance of the old and new passwords using this query:

```
select
 dbo.edit_distance_within(@s,@t,@d)
```

Where `@s` is the source string (old password), `@t` is the target (new password), and `@d` is the minimum change threshold.

**Clarification:**  The Levenshtein distance calculates the variance by counting how many individual character changes it would take to match the source to the target.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
DECLARE @s varchar(200) = 'stackoverflow',
        @t varchar(200) = 'lackdoversow',
        @d int = 5
select
     dbo.edit_distance_within(@s,@t,@d)
```

Result: `5`

Comment: That's a fascinating idea, if I can get at the ALTER_LOGIN statement to read the password before it's hashed.  Your function includes an argument (@d) that isn't in your example, though.  I assume that parameter is the desired variance?

Comment: I apologize, I'll update the second query.  Yes, @d is the desired change threshold.  If the Levenshtein count is less than the required threshold, it will return -1, which would be a great value to use in your `If` or `Case When` statement when changing passwords.

Comment: Please note the changes I've made to my answer.

Comment: @user3271228, If this is a necessity, I would set up some kind of app or web form to change passwords, and pass that new and old password through the Levenshtein method, then if the result <> -1, run the `ALTER_LOGIN` query with the textbox values.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Sev09--Unfortunately, I don't see a way to intercept the old and new passwords when they're changed from the SQL Server Management Studio and I'd need to do that to apply your function.  I tried using the event data from the ALTER_LOGIN event (via a trigger and EVENTDATA()), but the SQL for changing the passwords isn't included...That's a cool function, though, and it solves the basic problem.  There are just other circumstances barring the way in my particular case.

Comment: @user3271228 - Perhaps I wasn't clear.  There would be no need to recall the old password.  The user would just enter their old password in the created web form, which would be passed through to the query as a parameter.